# Test coverage for the REST API endpoints?

Tags: java, api, rest, testing, integration-testing

My project - Java web service, spring boot, maven.

I am starting the spring application context and running the integration tests against REST API endpoints. And I want to see the report with integration test coverage, like this:

**List of endpoints (4):**

1. api/status  --->>> not covered
2. api/users  --->>> not covered
3. api/countries  --->>> covered
4. api/offices  --->>> covered

So, I would like to see the **list of all endpoints** I have in my web service and whether each endpoint is covered by Integration test.

For unit tests I am using JaCoCo but it gives me only code coverage which is not exactly what I am looking for.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You can't, what you can measure is actuall java classes which are your restendpoint implementations, if you want to see a similar report, user a standard name for your Rest endpoint classes

Answer (score 0):

https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/testing/coverage/rest.html proprietary api testing tool seems to provide support for measuring rest api test coverage